# How to keep state in component after calling other component

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I have two components for my search function, one to select the search filters and one to do the search query. Every time I select a filter the state is reloaded, therefore I am not able to select more than one filter. Is there a way to call the search component and have my searchfilter component to keep its state ?

In my searchfilters component I have this:

```
let state = _.extend({}, this.state);
state.filters = this.toggleFilter(filterObj, state.filters);
this.setState(state);
this.props.searchWithFilters(state.filters);
```

In my search component I have:

```
<SearchFilters searchWithFilters={this.searchWithFilters.bind(this)} />
```

And I have this Method:

```
searchWithFilters(filters) {
let state = _.extend({}, this.state);
state.filters = filters;
this.setState(state);
this.props.search(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only the state of your `SearchComponent` to store the filters instead of using the state of `SearchFilters` too. The `toggleFilter` method would be in the `SearchComponent` too and it would send it as a prop as well (or maybe you could do it in `searchWithFilters` if you always call them both together). Finally, you would have to send the filters as a property to the `SearchFilters` component.

```
 <SearchFilters filters={this.state.filters} 
searchWithFilters={this.searchWithFilters.bind(this)} />
```

Then, `searchWithFilters` would receive only the new filter and add it to the state of the `SearchComponent`. It could be something like:

```
searchWithFilters(filterObj) {
   let state = _.extend({}, this.state);
   state.filters = [];
   state.filters.push(this.state.filters);
   state.filters.push(filterObj);
   this.setState(state);
   this.props.search(this.state);
}
```

You could also store them in redux, which could be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Am I able to pass the state of searchfilters to the search component ?

Comment: You can, of course, but the way I put it you wouldn't need to use the state of SearchFilters, the filters prop would be enough if you update the filters in the SearchComponent state using searchWithFilters or another callback method.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how searchWithFilters may be. It takes the new filter and adds it to the state. In the SearchFilters component just use this.props.filters instead of this.state.filters.

Answer (score 0):

You're just overwriting your filters every time so if you need to keep track of the previous filters I would store them in an array.

```
searchWithFilters(filters) {
    let state = _.extend({}, this.state);
    state.filters = [];
    state.filters.push(filters);
    this.setState(state);
    this.props.search(this.state);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in my state I already have filters defined as an array. That should also do the trick right ?